# Wordpress: (php)Change the 'Add to Cart' text to 'Request for quote' when product price is empty or equal to zero

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the text of the Add to cart  button when the price is empty or equal to zero, however I want to keep the user able to add it to the cart since my checkout page is also RFQ.
I am using this code but it isn't working:

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart_text, $product ) {
    if (empty  ( $product->get_price()) ||  ( $product->get_price()) == "0.00" ) {
        $add_to_cart_text = __( 'Request for quote', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $add_to_cart_text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'filter_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: `$product->get_price()) == "0.00"` should just be `$product->get_price()) == 0 ` but for a product with an empty price, no button is displayed on the single product page, 
is that your issue? or what do you mean specifically by 'it isn't working'

Comment: I mean nothing is changing, I still see  'Add to cart'

Comment: Then it seems more like an issue with other custom code, your theme or other plugins you use. I've tested your code (outside of my previous comment) it's the basis for the answer to your question, so your code works in general 
and only similar answers to your question can be given